# Hibernate bidirectional One-to-Many Cascade.All not working

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, cascade

I have the following two class `Answer` and `SubAnswer`:

```
@Entity
public class Answer {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "answer", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    List<SubAnswer> subAnswers;
}
public class SubAnswer {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    Answer answer;
}
```

and I save them like this

```
{
   Answer ans = new Answer();
   List<SubAnswer> subAnswerList = new ArrayList<SubAnswer>();
   ans.setSubAnswers(subAnswerList);
   ans.add(new SubAnswer());
   ans.add(new SubAnswer());
   entityManager.save(ans);
}
```

when I save an `Answer`, I think it should save the  `SubAnswer`s and it saves them but it does not set the `SubAnswer.answer` field and it remain null

Comment: That's expected. You need to set the SubAnswer's answer by yourself. Saving objects inside the collection doesn't mean changing its state. That's one of the reasons you should have an addSubAnswer() method in Answer, that would set its parent answer to `this`.

Comment: So if I simply remove the ManyToOne field, hibernate sets it automatically?

Comment: There would be no field to set anymore if you didn't have the field.

Comment: but there should be a corresponding field in the database to hold one-to-many join information. i mean that

Comment: If you remove the ManyToOne, the OneToMany would have to become the owner side, and Hibernate would indeed populate the join table or the join column (depending on your mapping) automatically.

Comment: I remove the ManyToOne ant it remains null in database, also according to https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/ (not official) you are wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159343/discussion-between-hossein-nasr-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: How did you map the OneToMany? Not sure which of the hundreds of lines in this article makes me wrong. But no, I'm not wrong.

Comment: I just removed the `mappedBy` part from my question, and also remove ManyToOne field

Comment: So that uses the default mapping of a OneToMany unidirectional association, which consists in using a join table to map the association, not a join column. You need a JoinColumn annotation on the subAnswers field.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly couldn't say if this is good / bad practice but I've had a similar problem and fixed it by using the following:

```
@Entity
public class Answer {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
    List<SubAnswer> subAnswers;
}

@Entity
public class SubAnswer {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
    Answer answer;
}
```

This gives you a 'answer_id' column in your SubAnswer table and allows you to perform your:

```
{
   Answer ans = new Answer();
   List<SubAnswer> subAnswerList = new ArrayList<SubAnswer>();
   ans.setSubAnswers(subAnswerList);
   ans.add(new SubAnswer());
   ans.add(new SubAnswer());
   entityManager.save(ans);
}
```

and still get the answer_id populated.

On a side note, I'm barely getting started with hibernate so if anyone has any opinions on whether this ok or a truly terrible solution I'd appreciate hearing about that!